# How can a OneDrive user sync in his/her hard drive a folder I've shared from my own OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint, cloud-storage

I have a large multi-GB folder I've shared with a colleague and I've sent him a link with which he can download everything, but how could he "sync" my folder using the OneDrive client so whenever I add a new file he will automatically download only the new files? (and without having to take space off his own OneDrive since he has less free space than the size of my shared folder).

My account is a OneDrive for Business account which includes Sharepoint (just in case it makes a difference).

Comment: The user can’t.  They can only download the files you have shared.

Comment: When you share folders with Edit permissions, people you share with can add the shared folders to their own OneDrive. If the user doesn't add the shared folder to his/her OneDrive, he/she can't sync this folder into his/her local drive with his/her OneDrive.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @HerbGu. Doing that (syncing this folder into someone else's local drive) would take storage space from the other user?